# New Product Alert / Send Email Notification

Tags: product, email, alert, adminnotification

I would like to send an email notification to the admin whenever a new product is created.

Answer (score 1):

For this case you need an custom extension which contain below feature

1. Create a  transactional email template which is  create email html
2. using magento event catalog_product_save_after  fire the email

Comment: Technically you only need the first step if you want a specific transnational email. Technically you could use a simple plain text email but that really depends on the user's needs.

Comment: I want something very similar and was hoping for some help. I want to send an email to the admin if any product is disabled. I was thinking I could hook into the event catalog_product_save_after.. would that work?